# Why is the series $\sum \left(\frac23\right)^k$ converging to 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac23\right)^k
$$
and apparently it converges to $2$. What is the method to use to find this?

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a^k=\frac{a}{1-a}$$If $|a|<1$

Comment: That is a simple fact from geometric series. I am stupid for missing it :/

Comment: @OlivierOloa My bad.